# I need to using angular to build a grid form dynamic build component

Tags: angular, angular-material, grid

this is my code to build a multi dynamic component using Angular

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    for (let index = 0; index < this.items.length; index++) {
      setTimeout(()=>{
        let img = this.items[index];
        const dynamicComponentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(ProductComponent);
        // this.container.clear();
        const targets = this.widgetTargets.toArray();
     
          let target = targets[index];
          let instance: any = target.createComponent(dynamicComponentFactory);
          instance.instance.img = img;  
          this.instances[index] = instance;
        
    },100)
    }
  }
```

and this is the html

```
<table>
    <tbody *ngFor="let data of items; let index = index" >
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <ng-template #dynamic></ng-template>
                </td>
            </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

how can I to display these dynamic components in table from 4 columns GRID (it show all components in 1 column in my code)

Comment: I added one more layer of components, it serves as a wrapper and with flex layout for the grid. it can contain other wrapper or regular components. PS: take a look at "ng-dynamic-component" maybe if it can help you

Comment: Maybe your ngFor have to be inside the `<tr>` tag.